# Modify runtime > probing attribute web.config using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I host an application on IIS with the following structure:

```
IISAPP
  - bin
  - plugins
  - scripts
  - default1.aspx
  - web.config
```

Within the Plugins directory, I host several other ASPX apps within it's own directory so that structure would look like this:

```
IISAPP
  - bin
  - plugins
    - MyPlugin
      - bin
      - scripts
      - default2.aspx
      - web.config
  - scripts
  - default1.aspx
  - web.config
```

When I navigate to http://IISAPP/ the default1.aspx page is served which is great. When I navigate to http://IISAPP/plugins/MyPlugin/default2.aspx the page is not served and it is complaining that it cannot find the dll's. This is because the plugin app is looking for the dll's in the bin folder top level application.

I proceeded to add the `<probing privatePath="plugins/MyPlugin/bin" />` tag. This solved the issue of serving up default2.aspx.

**The problem**

These plugins will be installed using an installer. I have to somehow change that private path to include all folders. So if I add a "MyPlugin2", I will have to modify the probing tag in the top level web.config to be `<probing privatePath="plugins/MyPlugin/bin;plugins/MyPlugin/bin" />`.

I need to modify the `privatePath` attribute in the below web.config inside of the `probing` element in the `runtime` section using C# and then saving the config file. I have tried to  do this using the configuration manager but cannot locate the proper path. When it seems right, it results in null.

I played around with the following too:

```
var config = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));
var runtimeNode = config.Root.Element("runtime").Element("assemblyBinding").Element("probing").Attribute("privatePath");
```

In this case the document loads but for the life of me I cannot get to that privatepath value to update it and save the config.

I also tried `XMLDocument` but I cannot load the xml due to line 1 in the web.config. I don't really want to remove it and apart from that, the solution feels a bit sloppy.

**UPDATE**
I tried the following:

```
var config = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"));
System.Xml.Linq.XElement runtimeNode = config.Root.Element("runtime");
System.Xml.Linq.XElement assemblyBindingNode = runtimeNode.Element("assemblyBinding");
System.Xml.Linq.XElement probingNode = assemblyBindingNode.Element("probing");
System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute att = probingNode.Attribute("privatePath");

att.Value = "new value";
config.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Web.config.xml"));
```

It works up to the runtime node. it is like it cannot find the assemblyBinding node within the runtime node.

**web.config**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MyProject.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebFilePath" value="D:\Web Solutions\WEB" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <probing privatePath="INeedToChangeThisValue" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi can I ask what you're trying to achieve here? This might help when giving answers

Comment: @matt_lethargic, I added to the start of the question of what the goal is.

Comment: Ok, I get it, when you say the plugins are 'installed' do you have another tool that installs them? Is it that tool that installs them or the site itself?

Comment: @matt_lethargic, the top level app installs them. It creates the directory structure, and should then modify its own web.config file to include the new bin folder. The code I tried above sits in the top level app. this is where I cannot get it working.

Comment: @matt_lethargic, I added another solution that I tried which did not work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an xml namespace issue, got it working using `XmlDocument`.
My only concern is that usually ASP.Net will do assembly resolving at startup which means that you might need to restart the app after setting the `privatePath`, I've used `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("runtime")`, that might refresh the section and get things working.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/web.config"));

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ass", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");

var probing = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//runtime/ass:assemblyBinding/ass:probing", nsmgr) as XmlElement;
probing?.SetAttribute("privatePath", "bin;plugins/bin");

xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/web.config"));

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("runtime");
```